# W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/freya/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am using elementary os freya. I am trying to install MongoDB by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide.

I added GPG Keys

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Followed to next step of *Creating a List File*

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

When I run `sudo-apt-update`. I have following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/freya/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/freya/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

freya isn't a release name of ubuntu
instead of $(lsb_release -sc)  try  trusty 
which is the name of ubuntu distribution used for freya

Comment: perfect solution @AAS